Batch Script to unzip and rename files depending on folder name and file date modified?
I have a bunch of zip files in separate folders that contain multiple files that need to be renamed. I have 0 experience with batch scripting, so I've been having copilot AI help me, and it's gotten me about 85% of the way there, but can't seem to get me to 100%.
For context:
I have a bunch of folders that all have the name "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", and so on. Each folder contains a zip file with a varying number of files in it.
I want the script to go into each "Sheet" folder, and rename the file according to the following format:
YYYY-MM-DD_{markup}_Sheet#.pdf
The date (YYYY-MM-DD) should be pulled from the date modified of the file. The script I have right now is doing that just fine.
If the original file name has either "eak markup", "CMS Markups" "CMS Markup", or "cms markup" in it, then the {markup} should be replaced by either "eak markup" or "cms markup" as appropriate. If the file does NOT have any of those in the original name, then there should be nothing in the {markup} section of the new file.
And the "Sheet#" should be replaced with the name of the folder.
Finally, there may be some files that have the same date modified. In that case, I would like the code to append the new file name with "_R1".
The code I've developed thus far is copied below:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Set the base directory
set "baseDir=C:\Users\bkirtland\desktop\SN"

rem Loop through each "Sheet" folder
echo Starting to process folders in %baseDir%...

for /d %%D in ("%baseDir%\Sheet*") do (
    set "foldername=%%~nD"
    echo Found folder: !foldername!
    pushd "%%D"
    
    rem Check for zip files
    if exist *.zip (
        echo Unzipping files in %%D...
        for %%Z in (*.zip) do (
            echo Unzipping %%Z...
            powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Path '%%Z' -DestinationPath '.' -Force"
        )
    ) else (
        echo No zip files found in %%D.
    )

    rem Create a temporary list of PDF files
    set "fileList="
    for %%F in (*.pdf) do (
        set "fileList=!fileList! "%%F""
    )

    rem Process each PDF file from the temporary list
    for %%F in (!fileList!) do (
        echo Processing File: %%F
        
        rem Get the modified date in YYYY-MM-DD format
        for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%A in ('forfiles /m "%%~nxF" /c "cmd /c echo @fdate"') do (
            set "month=%%A"
            set "day=%%B"
            set "year=%%C"
            set "modDate=!year!-!month!-!day!"
        )
        echo Modified Date: !modDate!
        
        rem Determine the markup
        set "markup="
        echo %%F | findstr /i "eak markup" >nul && set "markup=eak markup"
        echo %%F | findstr /i "CMS Markup" >nul && if not defined markup set "markup=cms markup"
        echo %%F | findstr /i "CMS Markups" >nul && if not defined markup set "markup=cms markup"
        echo %%F | findstr /i "cms markup" >nul && if not defined markup set "markup=cms markup"
        echo Markup: !markup!

        rem Construct the new file name
        if defined markup (
            set "newName=!modDate!_!markup!_!foldername!.pdf"
        ) else (
            set "newName=!modDate!_!foldername!.pdf"
        )
        
        rem Handle naming conflicts
        set "counter=0"
        :checkConflict
        if exist "!newName!" (
            set /a counter+=1
            if defined markup (
                set "newName=!modDate!_!markup!_!foldername!_R!counter!.pdf"
            ) else (
                set "newName=!modDate!_!foldername!_R!counter!.pdf"
            )
            goto checkConflict
        )
        
        echo New File Name: "!newName!"
        
        rem Rename the file
        ren "%%F" "!newName!"
        
        rem Pause for debugging
        pause
    )

    popd
)

echo Done!
pause

When I run the script, it jumps straight to my folder "Sheet10". It unzips the zip file just fine, and the two files that are within that particular zip folder are named:
10 TYPICAL  CROSS SECTION - ROUTE 6_eak markup_2024-10-15.pdf
608020_BR2(SN_Route 6 - Typical Approach Section_SH)-TYP CROSS SECTION.pdf
This is what the command prompt displays when I run the script:
Starting to process folders in C:\Users\bkirtland\desktop\SN...
Found folder: Sheet10
Unzipping files in C:\Users\bkirtland\desktop\SN\Sheet10...                                                             Unzipping 10 TYPICAL  CROSS SECTION - ROUTE 6_eak markup_2024-10-15.zip...                                              Processing File: "10 TYPICAL  CROSS SECTION - ROUTE 6_eak markup_2024-10-15.pdf"
Modified Date: 2024-10-15
Markup: eak markup
New File Name: "2024-10-15_eak markup_Sheet10.pdf"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Press any key to continue . . .

It seems like it's having an issue actually renaming the files (line 76). It builds the name correctly, but doesn't rename the file. Any ideas??

So many levels of parentheses - very difficult to maintain - try using subroutines. I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) as ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs (See for/f from the prompt for documentation). Whilst developing, use ECHO ren … so that the ren is "disarmed" by simply being reported instead of being executed - remove the echo to activate - can be a life-saver. Obviously can also use with del, copy, move and other ptentially-destructive commands…

Fundamentally, you can't have a label (:checkConflict) within a code block (parenthesised sequence of commands) - it messes with the loop's processing.
Use
    ...
    set "counter=0"
    CALL :checkConflict
    
    echo New File Name: "!newName!"

    ...

within the loop and
echo Done!
pause

GOTO :eof

:checkConflict
if exist "!newName!" (
 set /a counter+=1
 if defined markup (
  set "newName=!modDate!_!markup!_!foldername!_R!counter!.pdf"
 ) else (
  set "newName=!modDate!_!foldername!_R!counter!.pdf"
 )
 goto checkConflict
)
GOTO :eof

at the end.
the call executes an internal subroutine (call :label - call label would execute an external subroutine from file label.bat)
The goto :eof (colon required; label :eof is defined as end-of-file, which exits the subroutine/mainline) simply terminates the (subroutine's) processing.
...and the rest should be plain-sailing.
